# Global shortcut work but system play Error sound

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, nsevent

I create global shortcut with this code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

     [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent * theEvent) {

       int modiferKeys = NSControlKeyMask | NSAlternateKeyMask;

            if (([theEvent keyCode] == 7 && modiferKeys)) {
               NSLog (@"%@",@"work");
            }
        }];
}
```

This code work perfect, but when some application have a focus (for example Xcode, AppStore...) the system play Error sound.
How fix it?
Thaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different way to implement a global hot key is using `RegisterEventHotKey`, declared in CarbonEvents.h.  The docs for it might be under "legacy", but as far as I can tell from the header, it's not deprecated and is available in 64-bit code.